# apache+Passenger+Railsのリクエスト処理時間が長すぎる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

初めて質問を投稿させて頂きました。宜しくお願いします！

## 環境

- Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
- Phusion Passenger version 4.0.42
- Rails 3.2.18

質問させて頂きたいのはタイトルの通りなのですが、原因がわからず困っています。
apacheのTimeoutは120秒に設定しているのですが、本当に極稀に予期せぬ不具合が発生し、原因を調べてみると、
apacheのアクセスログが

> [19/Nov/2015:07:35:37 +0900] "GET /XXX HTTP/1.1" 200  6 6369825
>   [19/Nov/2015:07:30:34 +0900] "GET /XXX HTTP/1.1" 200  7201 7201738623
>   [19/Nov/2015:09:45:02 +0900] "GET /XXX HTTP/1.1" 200  3 3323601

このようになっており、明らかに120秒を超えているにも関わらずStatusは200を返してしまっています。
Railsの方のログを確認した所,呼ばれたアクションの最初の行のログが下記のようになっています。

> [2015-11-19 07:35:38] Hoge#fuga called
>   [2015-11-19 09:30:34] Hoge#fuga called
>   [2015-11-19 09:45:03] Hoge#fuga called

となっており、後続の処理も何もなかったかのようにきっちり完了してしまっています。
つまり、07:30にapacheにきた通信が09:30になってから、いきなり何もなかったかのように
正常に処理を行ったようなログになっております。

なぜこのような事が起きたのか？防ぐ手立てはないのか？
些細な事でも構いませんのでご教授願えればと思います。

理想的には、120秒以上経過したリクエストは処理せず500などのエラーステータスを返せれば良いなと考えています。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: サーバが何か分かりませんが、`httpd.conf`で`Timeout 120`を追加したということでしょうか？また、Rubyの方でのTimeoutは設定しておりますか？対策の前にボトルネックの調査が済んでいないように見受けられますが、他なにか調査したことはございますか？

Comment: > httpd.confでTimeout 120を追加したということでしょうか？
おっしゃる通りです。
> Rubyの方でのTimeoutは設定しておりますか？
特に行っておりません。ただ、そもそもRailsのとあるアクションが実行されて、初めの行で **時間付きのログ** を吐いており、その時間が既に２時間経過している事からすると、ボトルネックどうこうというより、Passenger付近に何か不具合があるように考えています。
（ほぼ２時間ジャストという事も気になるが、原因がわかっておりません）

他の調査としては、apacheのエラーログ等確認しましたが、特にエラーは見受けられませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

Apacheのログを見るとタイムスタンプが入れ替わってますね。
これは、Apacheのログの出力タイミングによるもので Passenger と Rails が遅いのだとわかります。

> つまり、07:30にapacheにきた通信が09:30になってから、いきなり何もなかったかのよう

こういうことではないでしょうか↓

7:30 apache（A）のリクエストが来た
7:35 apache （B）のリクエストが来た
未明頃 (B) が終了して Apacheが応答を返した → 7:35 のログが出力される
9:30頃 (A) が終了 Apacheが応答を返した → 7:30 のログが出力される

Apacheの`Timeout`は リクエストを受ける際のタイムアウトですので 今回のように リクエストを受けてから応答を返すまでが長過ぎる場合はタイムアウトしません。

PassengerかRailsでタイムアウトの設定はできないでしょうか？
（コレについてはよくわからないので回答できません。悪しからず。）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございますっ
take88様がおっしゃるように、Passenger, Rails付近が遅いと言いますか...何かが発生し処理が止まった？そして２時間後に動き始めた？ような挙動が見受けられます。

> ApacheのTimeoutはリクエストを受けてから応答を返すまでが長過ぎる場合はタイムアウトしません。
なるほど・・・だとするとPassengerあたりに何かあるかもしれませんね。
Passengerなどには今回使えそうなTimeoutの設定は見つけれていません。あれば良いのですが・・・

もう少し自分の方でも調査を進めてみます！